# Using @Entity Class When Table Doesn't Exist

Tags: java, sql-server, spring

I have several database tables that my Spring MVC/JPA application refers to using the `@Entity` and `@Table` Annotations. I've run into the issue where if my application switches between database connections, some tables that exist on database 1 may not exist in database 2 (as we are following the SDLC cycle and promoting table additions/changes after they get the "OK"), thus resulting in an SQL Exception when the application server starts.

Does spring offer a way to mark specific `@Entity` Classes as "Optional" or "Transactional" so there are no database Exceptions returned because of nonexistant tables?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there is no option to do that.

You can add automatic update of schema in Hibernate, but you mentioned that you are doing this manually.

Hibernate is validating the schema, when he establishes connection. You use `@Entity`, so he looks for that table and throws an error if there is no with the name specified.